# Change the colour of each property in a list (HANDLEBARS JS & CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, handlebars.js

Using Handlebars I'm able to show a list of artists taken from Spotify. I want to be able to change the colour and style of each artist but I don't know how to separate them to do so? How do I go about doing this? Many thanks for any help or pointing me in the right direction.

```
<script id="artists" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h2>artists
      </h2>
    <dl class="pull-left">
      <dd class="text-overflow" id="artistcolumn">
        <ol>
          {{#each items}}
          <li>{{name}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ol>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </script>
```

I've tried using :nth-of-type() or artistcolumn but it hasn't work?

[I'm trying to get it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExnbX.png)

Comment: Hello sir. Can you give more details please? What do you want to change exactly (which style)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added an image in the first post. I want it to be a different colour on each row. I think I may have solved it by changing the CSS of list.. is that the correct way to do so?

Comment: You could use use `li:nth-child(1){color:red;}; li:nth-child(2){color:blue;}; li:nth-child(3){color:green;}` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by setting the CSS of a list. Here is an example:

```css
li:nth-child(1){
color: blue;
}; 

li:nth-child(2){
color:orange;
}; 

li:nth-child(3){
color:green;
}
```

---

**Another method** to set a color for each list entry would be to add a color to each item you render.
If `items` is an Array of Objects you could set `items[index].color = #0000FF` and then apply the hex color to each `li` HTML element.